# Is there a way to save cookies that were baked without flour?

Tags: cookies, flour

I forgot to put flour into my cookies (though I was careful to remember the oatmeal, and I blame the lack of flour on that).  They are absolutely delicious, but also difficult to eat because they have more the consistency of goopy pie filling than a cookie that you could hold in your hand.  Ideas include mashing them up, balling them, and freezing; and mashing them up, adding flour, and rebaking.

I understand that at this point they'll never be quite like cookies, but I refuse to waste them, and that would be easier if I could get them into a more manageable to eat format.

Comment: If they contain enough butter they may firm-up enough just by storing them in the fridge.

Comment: I've had them in the fridge for a while, and they're still pretty mushy.  I'm thinking about freezing them as I mentioned.

Comment: Mix them with vanilla ice cream?

Comment: I wonder if you could coat in batter and deep fry...

Answer (score 1):

Once it's baked that's really it, re-baking them will likely ruin them. Why not make drop cookies and put them in the fridge? They'll keep for most of the week that way.